# How do I dynamically set the <div> to the correct length?

Tags: html, css

How can I set the height (dynamically) of the yellow `<div id="box">` to fit inside the `<div id="center">` without overlapping the `Hello World` section?

Please ignore the JavaScript, in the jsfiddle, its part of something else ;p

http://jsfiddle.net/XskMm/3/

Thank you for reading and answering!

EDIT:

I apologize for the poor phrasing the question. I'll try to explain exactly what I want.

There are two main `<div>`s on the page. I made one gray and one yellow. I wish to make the yellow div fit inside of the gray one (both length and width) and not protrude over the outline of the gray div.

My problem is that the `<h1>` and the `<hr />` are pushing the `<div id="box">` down (like they should), but the `<div id="box">` isn't shrinking to the appropriate height so that it does not extend over the bottom of the `<div id="center">`

Comment: what do you mean by the correct length?

Comment: @jterrace, I'll edit my question to be more specific

Comment: do you mean width and height. Dynamically in relation to what??

Comment: @Hussein, the width is perfect, but the height is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright... trying this again.  If this isn't what you want, let me know.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XskMm/8/

The code:

```
window.onresize = function() { myResizeFunc();  }

function myResizeFunc() {
    var DOMwidth = window.innerWidth? window.innerWidth: window.document.body.parentElement.clientWidth;
    var DOMheight = window.innerHeight? window.innerHeight: window.document.body.parentElement.clientHeight;
    if (DOMwidth>200) { document.getElementById('center').style.width = (DOMwidth-100) + 'px'; }
     else { document.getElementById('center').style.width = '100px'; }
    if (DOMheight>300) {
        document.getElementById('center').style.height = (DOMheight-100) + 'px';
        document.getElementById('box').style.height = (DOMheight-122) + 'px';
    }
     else {
         document.getElementById('center').style.height= '200px';
         document.getElementById('box').style.height= '178px';
    }

}

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    myResizeFunc();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Hopefully I'll be able to write functions like that on my own someday soon. I'll make sure to give you credit in a comment (whenever I use it).

Comment: @Michael, does this function work cross-browser? It works in jsfiddle, but when I test it out in chrome, the height of the `<div id="box">` is too large. It extends over the bottom of `<div id="center">`

Comment: For me, it works in FF (3.6.13), Opera (11.01), Chrome (9.0.597.98), Safari (5.0.3), and IE8 (.0.6001.18702).  If it does not work as intended in some other browser, MooTools and jQuery are built with cross-browser functionality in mind, so using [Mootools' setStyle(s) functions](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Style) should clear up any problems of that sort.

Comment: @Mchael, did you test outside of jsfiddle?

Comment: @Sime `window.addEvent('domready', function()` is MooTools.  Everything else is normal JS.  @Dbz Nope.  If you have it on another site and want to link it, I can try to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you have this:

```
<div id="center">
    <h1> ... </h1>
    <div id="box"> ... </div>
</div>
```

The #center element has a height of 300px.
The H1 element has an variable height (its height is not fixed).
And you want the #box element to take up the remaining height. like do:

```
#box height = #center height - H1 height
```

That cannot be done in CSS. The possible solutions are:

a) JavaScript
b) HTML Tables
c) Let the H1 element have a fixed height (I recommend this!)

Comment: @Dbz Just set fixed heights to all of the above mentioned elements. For instance: #center to 500px, H1 to 50px, #box to 450px.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution- why not abandon `<div> #center` altogether? Since the header will always be on top and you want the height of the bounding area to be the same, try experimenting with this:

`<h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>

    <div id="box" class="bound">

        <p class="drag square"> One </p>

        <p class="drag square"> Two </p>

    </div>`

That way, your markup is simplified, and you don't have to worry about expanding the height of `div #box`. (Note: Of course, you'll have to switch around some of the CSS to accommodate the new layout).

Comment: Well, the `<div id="center"` is the basic structure of the page- I need it =/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand- if you apply the properties you have like height, etc for `div #center` to `div #box`, why not let `div #box` be the the page structure? Or are you saying that there are other elements in the page, and that `div #center` is a main page container.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying ;p  (I just haven't added them yet)

Comment: Ok- in that case, I would suggest just letting the container div have width and height at 100% (or whatever specs you'd like it to have), and then have the `div #box` have a fixed height and width. That way, other elements in `div #center` can flow around the box without interfering with it's internal components.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a top margin on the `<div id="box">`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you meant.  If not, you're going to have to explain your question better.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XskMm/7/

The code:

```
window.onresize = function() { myResizeFunc();  }

function myResizeFunc() {
    var DOMwidth = window.innerWidth? window.innerWidth: window.document.body.parentElement.clientWidth;
    if (DOMwidth>200) { document.getElementById('center').style.width = (DOMwidth-100) + 'px'; }
     else { document.getElementById('center').style.width = '100px'; }
}

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    myResizeFunc();
});
```

Comment: Sigh... looks like I answered the wrong question.  "How can I set the **length** (dynamically) of the yellow..."   You meant height.  If you're going to ask people to help you out, please put some minimal effort into asking the correct question.  `#box { background-color: #FF3; height: 278px; border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px; opacity: 0.5; }`  Use 278px as the height of box instead of whatever you had.

Comment: I apologize. It's not that I didn't put minimal effort into asking the question (you can look at other questions I've asked), I just don't really know how to describe what I would like better than what I did. I'll try to edit the original question again. I sincerely apologize =/

Comment: @Michael, is the question better worded?

Comment: Alright, well, next time, if you mean height, describe it with "height."  *Even if you're referring to width*, I would still avoid using the word "length."  Good luck on your drag-n-drop project.

Comment: In response to your second comment, it was never overlapping the Hello World section on my screen, but rather it was running off the bottom of the gray center div... probably due to us using different browsers.  That said, yes, it's better.  At least we all definitely know what dimension is being discussed now.  :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify. The last thing I want to do is piss off the people who help me. I've spent a lot of time helping people myself, and it's a horrible experience when the person asking for help is lazy, ambiguous, and unhelpful themselves.

Comment: We're here to help, but yeah, it does get frustrating when the person seeking help clearly exerts no effort.  I can see now that that is not the case here.  Keep your good attitude, show that you are trying, etc., and people will be more willing to reciprocate.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and in regards to your question, it *can be done* dynamically, which I think is something that has yet to be shown, so I will post a second answer to accomplish that.

Comment: @Michael, I posted an answer of my own which answers the question (I figured it out). I would, however, still like to see yours because it will most likely be different than mine; thus, a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of the comments lead me to this idea, mainly Sime's suggestion.

The `<div id="box">` is pushed down off of `<div id="center">` height wise because of `<h1>` and `<hr />`.

To make `<div id="box">` shrink accordingly (height wise), I set `<h1>` to a **fixed-percentage** and `<div id="box">` to a fixed-percentage.

```
#box {
    min-height: 90%;

    background-color: #FF3;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

h1 {
    height: 10%;
}
```

The percentages total `1.0`, so they will fill up the entire `<div id="center">`.

Comment: Even if this "works," it will have problems.  When the center div gets short, Hello World will start being smushed badly.  Similarly, when the center div gets very tall, the Hello World heading will be far too tall.  I just posted a new answer.  It should do what you're looking for.  If not, let me know.

Comment: @Michael, you're right. I didn't think of the consequences of being too tall- only too short which (in practicality) isn't an issue.